# How to override / substitute Error Page handling when using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using the Azure AD B2C .Net core Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI library (installed using NuGet) in a ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC Web App.

I would like to be able to change the Error page, however it ignores any custom or Developer mode error pages.

Does anyone know how I can override the error handling and/or any other pages of this library?

This is the page (github) that gets returned for any Azure B2C errors.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Azure/AzureAD/Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI/src/Areas/AzureADB2C/Pages/Account/Error.cshtml

I have created a custom error page and have the following in my startup. Everything else uses either this custom page or the default developer exception page depending on mode.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Account/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Comment: Which environment are you working on?

Comment: I have tried development and production...same result!

Comment: I am not sure about the package, but the error and other pages can be customized using Page customization in B2C. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your Startup.Configure() method:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/AzureADB2C/Account/SignedOut")
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/SignedOut");
    }
}));
```

Redirect to whatever page you want.