# Azure B2C Login and then navigate back throws error

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

We have a net core application that uses an Azure B2C sign in flow.

When the app starts up, the user is directed to the login page and then redirected to Home/Index on successful login.

But, in the browser the user is able to navigate back. When this is attempted the page fails to load a MicrosoftIdentity/Error page.

Is there something I need to set up that I haven't accounted for? We would want the user to stay on the Index page if they attempt to navigate back to the Azure B2C flow.

My StartUp.cs file has this:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMvcOptions(options => { })
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Comment: could you please add the error screenshot? if possible could you please give us the error code?

Comment: The error is a local 404 (can’t navigate to localhost:8080/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/error. 
It isn’t an azure b2c exception. I guess a work around would be to redirect to index from that path.. not sure how to do that I can add account/error but not microsoftIdentity/Account/Error. 
In any case I was hoping there was a way to handle this with azure b2c. Or if there was a less hacky solution to handle this.

Comment: can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391996/how-to-override-substitute-error-page-handling-when-using-the-microsoft-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

This also may happen if the redirect URI from your is not present in the app registered in AD as redirect URI, whatever URI you want to try to redirect must be available in redirect URI of Azure AD registered App.